# Why the password value shows and gets hide instantly when eye icon is toggled in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

```
<p:inputText id="productadminpassword" required="true"
            value="#{ApplicationManagedBean24.saveRequestMap['Object::MasterPassword']}"
            styleClass="inputField border" style="width:300px;"
            requiredMessage="Admin Password is mandatory"
            type="password">
            <p:ajax event="change" process="@this"
                update="@([id$=Adminpasswordcheck]) @([id$=prodeletepassword])"
                onstart="AdminpasswordMessageRemove();" />  
        </p:inputText>
        
        <i class="fa fa-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
    



<script type="text/javascript">
    
        $('#togglePassword').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('fa-eye-slash')){
               $(this).removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
               $(this).addClass('fa-eye');
               $('#SummaryForm\\:productadminpassword').attr('type','text');       
            }else{
               $(this).removeClass('fa-eye');
               $(this).addClass('fa-eye-slash');  
               $('#SummaryForm\\:productadminpassword').attr('type','password');
            }
        });
        </script>
```

These are the scripts and xhtml code.Actually when i toggle the eye icon,password input field gets displayed and instantly hidden ( ****** )like this and toggle becomes disabled.When the password is empty,eye icon toggle works fine.I checked the #id also.Kindly help me to know the reason why it behaves like that.

Comment: The code works fine in theory: https://jsfiddle.net/th9yerm4/ We need to see the final HTML instead, try creating a [mre] by inspecting the rendered code in the browser.

Comment: You will need to keep track of the state in your widget. Again, using the PrimeFaces password component has this all out of the box.